# Return value from method every XY second (Thread needed I think?) - Python

Tags: python, multithreading

Say I have a class:

```
Class MyWorker(object):
    def start(self, message, delay):
        while 1:
            print message
            time.sleep(delay)
```

Now this works as expected:

```
mw = MyWorker()
mw.start("hello world", 30)
```

ie. it prints `hello world` every 30 seconds.

However, say instead of `print`ing it, I want to DO something with it, e.g. do some calculation & save it to a database. I cannot use `return` because that would simply stop the `while` loop and so I would get the value only once. How would I go about returning something from the method, while still calling the method every 30 seconds.

I know I can just do that in 'MyWorker' itself, but is there a way to keep the changes in `MyWorker` minimal, that is, do the calculations & saving outside `MyWorker`? I assume the best way would be some sort of signal, ie:

```
Class MyWorker(object):
    def start(self, message, delay, custom_signal):
        while 1:
            custom_signal(message)
            time.sleep(delay)
```

And then we can 'listen' to that signal, however, I don't know how to do it properly (best practise). Any hint?

Comment: Google "python producer consumer queue", that's the pattern you're looking for.

Comment: @AlexHall sweet, that might be just it!